# Сравнение объектов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

коллеги!

Мне нужно сравнивать объекты
Есть сцена в юнити с одной стороны три изображения, с другой стороны три текстовых поля в который описаны изображения и записаны в случайном порядке (игра в 2D
Пример
Фото слона надпись кролик
Фото кролика надпись слон
Фото тигра надпись тигр

Суть в том что мы переносим фото в на нужное текстовое поле и с помощью тригера узнаём что фото перенесено (стригер по верх текстового поля)

После всех переносом мы жмём кнопку проверить и должна происходить проверка

Не могу придумать как можно реализовать проверку

Буду рад готовым исходниками или статьям

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнивай по имени использованной текстуры

renderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture.name

Если имя slon то на картинке slon.